# Ruby net/http change var @read_timeout

Tags: ruby

Here is the code setting default timeout in `lib/ruby/2.2.1/net/http.rb`

```
require 'net/protocol'
require 'uri'

module Net   #:nodoc:
  autoload :OpenSSL, 'openssl'

  class HTTPBadResponse < StandardError; end
  class HTTPHeaderSyntaxError < StandardError; end

  ...

    def initialize(address, port = nil)
      ...
      @read_timeout = 60
      ...
    end

  ...
```

How can I change this variable in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change it directly.

```
url = URI.parse('http://google.com')

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.read_timeout = 100 #seconds
```